# Nothing renders upon embbeding a custom-element in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, custom-element

I am creating a React component where I will embbed a custom-component of a live video stream coming from a remote Machine/Robot. The live video streaming contains i.e Video, Status of machine etc.

The custom-component is:

`<qaa-video camera-url="http://---.-.-.-:----" port-number="----" freeze-timeout="---" onClick={playHandler}></qaa-video>`

When I embbed this element in React it does not renders any thing in the browser and nothing appears in console as well. Click handler also does not work.

I am expecting to get a video on screen and also I want to update a state variable as soon as machine status changes.

Comment: "qaa-video" is not a base HTML tag so I guess there is some other library on your page that typically handles this? What is that library? The documentation of it is relevant.